# How do I specify a specific file in my Xamarin/VisualStudio Project using Environment.SpecialFolder?

Tags: c#, xamarin, streamwriter

I am trying to append text to a text file, but I can't find anywhere how to actually locate an existing file.

```
 partial void MainBtn_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            var Pp = ("Selected Form Of Exchange: Paypal");
            string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments(WHAT DO I WRITE IN THIS SPACE??);
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new **StreamWriter(Path.Combine(mydocpath, "SelectPayment.txt")))
```

//I know that the file already exists, I just am trying different things.

```
            {

                outputFile.WriteLine(Pp);
```

}

So what do I do? Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you specify a file by combining a folder path and a file name to create a file path

```
// this returns the path to a folder
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));

// combine that with a file name to create a file path
string file = Path.Combine(path, "myFile.text");

// append text to file
File.AppendAllText(file, "this is the text I want to append);
```